MS project web version - create new template of working hours calendar
I'd like to edit working days for the MS project web version
This MS project version is built on top of MS Powerautomate platform of M365 (MS Dynamics) and it seems you need to adjust organization calendar template to define new non working days (like local public holidays).
There are several guidance materials (e.g. this) but many users have issues with the proposed procedure.
I also cannot find the "Add new template" button in MS Dynamics admin pages.
Would you help clarify the preconditions (licenses, or access rights) to adjust the work days settings in this MS project web app?

